# How to Create a VM and deploy an application in Azure Resource Group Template

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net, azure-resource-manager

I want to create a set of VMs using either the Resource Group Template in VS 2015 or utilise one of the [azure-quickstart-templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) as the basis for doing this.

My specific requirements are also to install a simple .exe application and modify its .ini file with a key that I want to pass from the template, i.e. seqno = copyindex() or similar.

Can anybody provide some guidance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple Windows VM you can use either a [DSC Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/9ad72f1f5f0008c14311be79eee036b871712394/dsc-extension-iis-server-windows-vm) or a [Custom Script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/9ad72f1f5f0008c14311be79eee036b871712394/windows-vm-custom-script/azuredeploy.json) extension on the VM.  Both of the samples in the azure-quickstart repo require you to figure out how to stage the artifacts needed for the extension (in this case the EXE and the script that installs the EXE).

If you go the VS 2015 route, you can start with a VM template, add the DSC or custom script extension and then the PowerShell script provided by Visual Studio will stage the artifacts for you if you make them part of the project.

[image]

You can also mix/match - grab a template from github, modify it in VS or take the VS PowerShell script and bring it into whatever workflow works best for you.

Note: one thing to keep in mind as well  - you need to pass the location of that EXE into the script that does the install - that script/vm will need to know where to get it from.  In the VS 2015 workflow you can use the parameter values of _artifactsLocation and just pass that value along to the installation script.  If you start with a quickstart template, you have to manage that yourself.